# Create an option menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I'm able to create an option menu in Android through XML file, but I would like to add the second menu programmatically just before the menu is added from XML.

In example: the code below adds a menu item search.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

If I add a new menu item programatically, like

```
   menu.add(0,Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE,"Gift box").setIcon(R.drawable.jingle_bell).
                setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

It is appearing after the Search menu item in Actionbar, but I need it before the search menu item.

What changes do I need to make?

Comment: you just have to add `orderInCategory`. To arrange your options in order.

Comment: hi, can u pls post answer, i m not getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.yourmenu, menu);
    menu.add(0,Menu.FIRST, Menu.NONE,"Gift box").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_refresh).
            setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}
```

**Update:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Its working in my phone update your menu.xml with this
    android:orderInCategory="200"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Answer (score 0):

Just set order for your item as,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.yourmenu, menu);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST, 1,"Gift box").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_refresh).
            setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}
```

`Third parameter` is order for above menu item. Now in your `menu.xml` set order for your item as,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below example

in XML :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_guide"
    android:title="title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_title"
    app:showAsAction="always"
     />
```

then copy below code to your activity :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
    return true;
}
```